A curious $q$-analog of $1-x$.
Let   $$\frac{1}{\sum_{n \geq 0}q^\binom{n}{2}x^n}=\sum_{n \geq 0}u(n,q)x^n.$$
Computations suggest that $u(n,q)$ is a polynomial in $q$ with integer coefficients of degree $\binom{n}{2}.$ The first polynomials are $ 1,-1, 1-q, -1+2q-q^3, 1-3q+q^2+2q^3-q^6.$
Have these polynomials been studied? If so, please give some references. I would be interested in some closed formula for $u(n,q).$
**Edit:**Perhaps the following observation may be useful:
$f(x)= \sum_{n \geq 0}q^\binom{n}{2}x^n$ satisfies $f(x)=1+x f(qx).$
Therefore $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ satisfies $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{g(qx)}}.$
Edit 2: The original problem which led to my question was the following: Let $a(n,q)=q^\binom{n}{2}$ for $n\geq 0$ and $a(n,q)=0$ for $n<0.$  Then the determinant of the Hankel matrix $H_n$ with entries $h_{i,j}=a(2-n+i+j,q)$ is $(-1)^\binom{n+1}{2}u(n,q).$ For example
$H_{5}= \left ( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0& 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 &1 & q \\0 & 1 & 1 &q & q^3 \\1 & 1 & q & q^3 & q^6 \\ 1 & q & q^3 & q^6 & q^{10} 
 \end{matrix} \right ).$

@Semiclassical: The summation begins with n=0.

The series on the LHS has appeared on this site much earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/332445/137524. (In particular they obtained the same functional equation as you, which is how I found it.) However, I wouldn't consider that answer very helpful for this one.

That said, a useful bit of terminology from that question is that such a series is known as a "partial theta function". (The ordinary theta functions are sums from $n=-\infty$ to $\infty$, so this series is only only over the "positive" part.)

Here is a method to compute these polynomials in terms of integer compositions. As discussed here, the reciprocal of a power series with leading term $1$ can be expressed as follows:
$$\frac{1}{1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n x^n$$
Here $$b_n=\sum (-1)^k a_{i_1}\cdots a_{i_k}$$
where the sum is over all $2^{n-1}$ integer compositions $(i_1,i_2,\cdots,i_k)$ of $n$. As an example, take $n=3$ for which the integer compositions of $3$ are $3=1+2=2+1=1+1+1$. Taking $a_n=q^{\binom{n}{2}}$, we have
\begin{align}
u(3,q)=b_3&=(-1)^1 a_3+(-1)^2[a_1 a_2 +a_2 a_1]+(-1)^3 a_1^3\\
&=-q^3+2q^0 q^1-(q^0)^3\\
&=-q^3+2q^1 -1
\end{align}
in agreement with the OP. For an example which goes beyond the OP, the integer compositions of $5$ are
\begin{align}
5&=4+1=3+2=2+3=1+4\\
&=3+1+1=1+3+1=1+1+3\\
&=2+2+1=2+1+2=1+2+2\\
&=2+1+1+1=1+2+1+1=1+1+2+1=1+1+1+2\\
&=1+1+1+1+1
\end{align}
Proceeding more rapidly this time, we find
\begin{align}
u(4,q)=b_4
&=-a_5+2a_4 a_1+2a_3a_2-3a_3 a_1^2-3a_2^2 a_1+4a_2 a_1^3-a_1^5\\
&=-q^{10}+2q^6 q^0 +2q^3 q^1-3q^3 (q^0)^2+4q^1 (q^0)^3-(q^0)^5\\
&=-q^{10}+2q^6+2q^4-3q^3+4q-1
\end{align}
which I have confirmed via Mathematica. So the coefficients in $u(n,q)$ evidently has an interpretation in terms of integer compositions. I feel like this can be strengthened further but it's beyond my expertise.
For completeness, here's Mathematica code to generate these polynomials in two ways. In both cases, the value of m dictates the polynomial $u(m,q)$ we want to extract. The first is directly from the power series,
SeriesCoefficient[1/(Sum[q^(n(n-1)/2) x^n, {n,0,m}]+O[x]^(m+1)),{x,0,m}]]

while second is summing over compositions directly,
Total[Times@@@(Flatten[Permutations/@IntegerPartitions[5],1]/.n_->-q^(n(n-1)/2))]

If we set m=10, in both cases we obtain
$$u(10,q)=-1 + 6 q - 10 q^2 - q^3 + 12 q^4 - 3 q^5 + q^6 - 6 q^7 + 2 q^9 - 
 3 q^{10} + 2 q^{11} + 2 q^{15} - q^{21}$$
For reference, the integer partitions of $7$ are \begin{align}
7&=6+1=5+2=4+3\\
&=5+1+1=4+2+1=3+3+1=3+2+2\\
&=2+2+2+1=3+2+1+1=4+1+1+1\\
&=2+2+1+1+1=3+1+1+1+1\\
&=2+1+1+1+1+1\\
&=1+1+1+1+1+1+1.
\end{align}

This is nice, but not the formula I am looking for.

I could not find a closed formula, only a recursion which I found for q=2 in OEIS A348901:
Let $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}q^\binom{n}{2}x^n$ which satisfies $f(x)=1+xf(qx).$ Then $\frac{1}{f(qx)}- \frac{x}{f(x)}= \frac{1}{f(x)f(qx)}$ and therefore $q^n u(n,q)=u(n-1,q)+\sum_{0\leq j \leq n}q^j u(j,q)u(n-j,q).$
Edit:
Together with Michael Schlosser, we finally found a formula for $u(n,q):$
Define a $q-$analog $\binom{n}{k}_q$ of the binomial coefficients by $$\binom{n}{k}_q=\sum_{j=0}^{\min(k,n)} q^{\binom{j+2}{2}}\binom{n-1-j}{k-j}_q$$ with initial values $\binom{n}{0}_q=q^{n+1}$ for $n \geq {-1}$ and $\binom{-1}{k}_q=0$ for $k>0.$
The first terms are
$\left( \binom{n}{k}_q \right)_{0\leq {n,k}\leq 5}= \left ( \begin{matrix} q & 0 & 0& 0 & 0&0  \\ q^2 & q^3 & 0 &0  & 0&0\\q^3 & 2q^4 & q^6 &0 &0&0 \\q^4 & 3q^5 & q^6+2q^7 & q^{10} & 0&0 \\ q^5 & 4q^6 & 3q^7+3q^8 & 2q^9+2q^{11} & q^{15}&0\\q^6&5q^7&6q^8+4q^9&q^9+6q^{10}+3q^{12}&q^{12}+2q^{13}+2q^{16}&q^{21} 
 \end{matrix} \right ).$
Let $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}q^{\binom{n}{2}}x^n.$ Then we get by induction
$x^k f(qx)^k =\sum_{n\geq k}\binom{n-1}{n-k}_{q}  (\frac{x}{q})^n.$
From $\sum u(n,q) x^n =\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{1+xf(qx)}=\sum (-1)^k x^k f(qx)^k$ we see that
$$u(n,q)=\frac{1}{q^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n-1}{k}_q.$$
For example,
$u(4,q)=\frac{1}{q^4}(q^4 –(3q^5)+(q^6+2q^7)-(q^{10}))=1-3q+q^2+2q^3-q^6.$
